# SQlite Full text search (FTS)?

Tags: sqlite

I have question about FTS on sqlite.

Create table :

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mail USING fts3(subject, body);
```

Insert demo data

```
INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) 
VALUES(1, 'software feedback' 'found it too slow');

INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) 
VALUES(2, 'software feedback', 'no feedback');

INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) 
VALUES(3, 'slow lunch order',  'was a software problem');
```

Code for search query

```
SELECT * 
FROM mail 
WHERE subject MATCH 'software*';    ==> Selects rows 1 and 2

SELECT * FROM mail WHERE body MATCH 'feedback';    ==>  Selects row 2

SELECT * FROM mail WHERE mail MATCH 'software*';    ==> Selects rows 1, 2 and 3

SELECT * FROM mail WHERE mail MATCH 'slow';        ==> Selects rows 1 and 3
```

However, when I want to search text in a word. ex: I want to search any word contain character "o":

Ex:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mail 
WHERE mail MATCH 'o';
```

I get no results ...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: FTS isn't searching text columns using a pattern. What you describe is a simple `LIKE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `LIKE` operator?  If you wanted any record from the `mail` table where the `mail` field had one or more `o` letters in it, you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE mail LIKE '%o%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I need query on big data. That's why I must use FTS. If we use "LIKE", it's work but very slow on big data.

Comment: I'm not sure I see any way around the performance problem if you really want to scan an entire string for a single character.